# Combined PHP and HTML in nodes and blocks

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm trying to find a way to translate blocks in a Drupal 7 site using PHP and HTML coding.
Now, my blocks in the current language of the site are written in HTML, but I am wondering if I could include a PHP script, using PHP code format in the block, in order to switch content if the language changes.

In general, is there a way that I could combine HTML and PHP code in a node/block/custom text?

I recently wrote PHP code in the header of a view (using the PHP code format), in order to print a message if the user is not logged in, but when I added HTML in it or before it, it stopped being displayed.

Comment: Have you enabled PHP Filter on the modules page? Also see: https://drupal.org/node/1046700

Comment: basically, all text that might/will have a need to be translated should be passed through the `t()` function (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7).  is that happening already?

Comment: "I recently wrote PHP code" - if you want us to be able to help you with this code, please show it. Otherwise we will probably suggest things you have already tried and either failed to implement properly, or implemented properly but found unsuitable for your needs.